# Why does `sort <(ls -l)` work but `sort < (ls -l)` fail?

Tags: bash, process-substitution

Today I'm learning something about fifo with this article: [Introduction to Named Pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156), which mentions `cat <(ls -l)`.

I did some experiments by using `sort < (ls -l)`, which pops out an error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`
```

Then I found I misadded an extra space in the command.

But, why this extra command will lead to this failure? Why must the redirect symbol be close to the `(`?

Comment: It should be noted that *nix shells splits things up based on whitespace which creates the tokens that Alec mentioned.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Because that's not an `<`, it's a `<()` which is completely different. This is called [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), it is a feature of certain shells that allows you to use the output of one process as input for another.

The `>` and `<` operators redirect output to and input from *files*. The `<()` operator deals with commands (processes), not files. When you run

```
sort < (ls)
```

You are attempting to run the command `ls` in a subshell (that's what the parentheses mean), then to pass that subshell as an input file to `sort`. This, however, is not accepted syntax and you get the error you saw.

Comment: Your answer is good, but `then sort is attempting to read the subshell as its input file` → this is obviously wrong, as Bash will not even parse the syntax. Neither `ls` nor `sort` is actually run.

Comment: @sebleblanc fair point, rephrased the answer, thanks.

Comment: There's no sub-shell in this case. `< (ls)` is not a valid token here.

Comment: @cuonglm no, because bash treats it as a syntax error. My point is that `(ls)` would run `ls` in a subshell.

Answer (score 22):

Because that's how it's meant to be.

`<(...)` in `bash` is the syntax for process substitution. It's copied from the same operator in `ksh`.

`<`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `&`, `;` are special lexical tokens in `bash` that are used to form special operators in different combinations. `<`, `<(`, `<<`, `<&`... each have their role. `<` is for redirection. `<file`, `< file` would redirect input from a file. `<'(file)'` would redirect input from a file called `(file)`, but `<(file)` is a different operator that is not a redirection operator.

`< (file)` would be `<` followed by `(file)`. In that context, in `bash`, `(file)` is not valid. `(...)` can be valid as a single token in some contexts like:

```
(sub shell)
func () {
  ...
}
var=(foo bar)
```

But not in

```
sort < (cmd)
```

In the `fish` shell, it's different. In `fish`, `(...)` is for command substitution (the equivalent of `$(...)` in `bash`). And `<` is for input redirection like in Bourne-like shells.

So in `fish`:

```
sort <(echo file)
```

would be the same as:

```
sort < (echo file)
```

That is:

```
sort < file
```

But that's something completely different from `bash`'s process substitution.

In the `yash` shell, another POSIX shell, `<(...)` is not for *process substitution* but for *process redirection*

In there,

```
sort <(ls -l)
```

Short for:

```
sort 0<(ls -l)
```

is a redirection operator. It's more or less equivalent to:

```
ls -l | sort
```

While in `bash`, the `<(ls -l)` is expanded to the path of a pipe, so it's more like:

```
ls -l | sort /dev/fd/0
```

In `zsh`, `(...)` is overloaded as a globbing operator (`(*.txt|*.png)` would expand to `txt` and `png` files) and as glob qualifier (`*(/)` for instance expands to directory files).

In `zsh`, in:

```
sort < (ls -l)
```

That `(ls -l)` would be treated as a glob qualifier. The `l` glob qualifier is to match on number of links and expects a number after `l` (as in `ls -ld ./*(l2)` would list the files with 2 links), so that's why you get a `zsh: number expected` error there.

`sort < (w)` would have given a `zsh: no matches found: (w)` error instead as `(w)` matches the files with empty name that  are writeable.

`sort < (w|cat)` would have sorted the content of the `w` and/or `cat` files in the current directory...

Comment: why `sort < $(ls -l)` gives this error: `bash: $(ls -l): ambiguous redirect`

Comment: @edwardtorvalds, because `$(ls -l)` expands to more than one word. Use quotes to prevent split+glob (`sort < "$(echo file)"`). Note that the behaviour or `bash` differs from that of POSIX sh in that bash does that split+glob there as well when non-interactive (not when called as `sh` though).

Comment: by looking at `ls -l | sort /dev/fd/0` I can say that output of `ls -l` is stored in `/dev/fd/0` and `sort` command reads it to give the desired output. I am using `tail -f --retry /dev/fd/0` to monitor that file but I am not getting any output. why? how can I read that file?

Comment: In fish, you can use `(foo | psub)` to achieve input process substitution; there is no substitute (ha) for output process substitution yet.